# want to impose predefined rectangle on PDF and save to those data to excel in java. How Can i do that in java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, icepdf

I want to impose predefined size rectangle on PDF. So I can scan those data which come under that rectangle on that PDF and want to save those data in to the excel sheet.

How can I do that in java?

Comment: Your question is kind of broad. It would be useful to focus it more by adding what you've tried so far. I don't know about adding the data to an Excel sheet. Extracting the data from the PDF can be done using iText: you can define a rectangle to restrict the text extraction to, using a `RegionTextRenderFilter`: [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279)

Comment: fill to Excel: get Apache POI. PDF: get PDFBox and look for ExtractTextByArea examples. However your question is very broad indeed. But it could work if you really know where the data is in the PDF.

Comment: As suggested by @TilmanHausherr, you can check [this example](http://read.pudn.com/downloads97/sourcecode/java/395274/PDFBox-0.7.3/src/org/pdfbox/examples/util/ExtractTextByArea.java__.htm).